# How do I setup q4wine step by step

Tags: networking

Since I downloaded it, I been having trouble trying to process the step by step on q4wine and still won't let me through. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

For me it posed problem when it asked for the console binary, maybe thats where you face the problem as well, so for that keep on clicking on 'next' button and when it asks for the console binary selecet any file from your file browser, 'any' means any.

Leave the arguments tab empty and click next and you're done.

This will work if you have the default wine setup and no guarantee if it works for sure, if doesn't you may download or create an empty *.cpp file and select it as the binary.

Comment: Oddly enough..this worked. I just picked a file "busybox" and ran with it and it worked as expected! Thanks Pancake! :)